# Json Schema for list with same propeties and element of fixed values

Tags: json, jsonschema

I've got this JSON:

```
{
    "A": "a",
    "B": "b",
    "C": "c",
    "TYPE_S": [
        {
            "ID": "S1"
            "X": "x",
            "Y": "y",
            "Z": "z",
        }
    ],
    "TYPE_C": [
        {
            "ID": "C1"
            "X": "x",
            "Y": "y",
            "Z": "z",
        },
        {
            "ID": "C2"
            "X": "x",
            "Y": "y",
            "Z": "z",
        }
    ]
}
```

and I need to define its schema. As you can see, `TYPE_S` and `TYPE_C` elements have the same fields. Moreover, `TYPE_S` can be variable while the two `TYPE_C` elements are fixed and always the same.

I tried to create the schema but I don't know how to define the same properties for the two types and also the fixed values for `TYPE_C`.

Could you help me? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Have a look at `$ref` https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring

Comment: I cant define any other schema :/

Comment: `$ref` doesn't require an external schema. It's most often used to reference within the same document. See, https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring#dollardefs. Read that section and give it a try. If you can't get it to work, update the question with what you've tried and we can try to help from there.